# Python variable scope within try/except blocks

Tags: python

I'm getting error :

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'process' referenced before assignment`

on the code below - how do I get the process object within the except block?

```
try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(list(args), 
                    shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except Exception, e:
    print process.communicate()
```

Comment: if you want, you could do something like `process = None` and then check that in the `except` block...

Comment: why do you want to communicate() when an exception is raised? it obviously won't work that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the one line you call fails, which means that `process` is never bound (because the code never makes it that far!). so there's no way to do that.

in other words, when you call `subprocess.Popen` an exception is raised, so there's no result to set `process` to.

Answer (score 2):

If an exception is raised, a process may not be created. Hence you can't assume the variable `process` will exist within the except block.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the general case "Exception" to something you actually expect.
Process is never known in the Exception block if it fails.
More here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions